# How do i check that car name entered by the user is Audi?

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, dictionary, object

class car:
def getdata(self):
self.n=int(input('Enter no. of cars: '))
a=[]
i=0
while i<self.n:
self.car=input('Enter cars: ')
self.owner=input('Enter owners name: ')
self.reg=input('Enter registration no.: ')
self.year=input('Enter year: ')
print('---------------------------------------')
print()
self.data={'car':self.car,'owner':self.owner,'regist no.':self.reg,'year':self.year}
a.append(self.data)
i+=1

```
    self.cars=a
    print(self.cars)
```

c=car()
c.getdata()

Comment: Did you try using the comparison operator `==` and the string `"Audi"`?

Comment: Yes, I did but I think i got wrong on my process

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call an **init**() method in the class, so that means that you will get an error if you try to run the code. You also were not quite clear in your question, so I will have to assume that this is what you want.

```
class car:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getdata(self):
        self.n=int(input('Enter no. of cars: '))
        a=[]
        i=0
        while i<self.n:
            self.car=input('Enter cars: ')
            self.owner=input('Enter owners name: ')
            self.reg=input('Enter registration no.: ')
            self.year=input('Enter year: ')
            print('---------------------------------------')
            print()
            if self.car.lower() == "audi":
                # Do something
                pass
            self.data={
            'car':self.car,
            'owner':self.owner,
            'regist no.':self.reg,
            'year':self.year
            }
            a.append(self.data)
            i+=1

stuff = car().getdata() # This is how you run it
```